# Follow Link in Microsoft Word Index

Tags: windows, indexing, ms-word, ms-office, tableofcontents

Using Microsoft Word 2007. I create a document with both a Table of Contents and an Index. I Save as PDF.

Inside the PDF, if I click on a page number in the TOC, it goes to that page. How do I get Word to do the same thing for page numbers in the index?

Thanks.

Update: It appears that TOC adds page numbers as internal Hyperlinks. Is there a way to get the Index to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

**Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>** before you **click** on **table of content item**.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. It works fine for a page number in the TOC. But you can't click on a page number in the Index. Is there any way to get it to work that way in the Index as well?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding... It seems that my option doesn't work with indexes. What you could do is to: 1) add bookmark for the word within the text 2) add link to the page number in index referring to appropriate bookmark. That could be done with VBA, I hope quite easily (but I didn't try it). You could also ask you question on [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com).

Comment: It appears that the TOC adds page numbers as internal hyperlinks. Curious that the Index does not do that also.